# += for GMP Floating-point Functions?

Tags: gmp

Is it possible to do a "+=" with GMP Floating-point Functions like this?

```
mpf_add (op1, op1, op2);
```

or must the three arguments always be different (requiring the use of a temp variable)?

(Same question goes for multiplication, subtraction, and division, although I'm sure the answer is the same for all four cases.)

Comment: You can. And you can even literally use += on mpf_class if you include <gmpxx.h> ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GMP manual states:

> GMP lets you use the same variable for both input and output in one
>   call.

I have done so with a variety of GMP functions and it has always worked properly but I don't know if I've ever done it with the mpf functions. I generally use the MPFR library and it states that you can use the same variable for input and output, too.